# Planetary tags for our solar system versus exoplanets

Tags: discussion, tags

So far we have tags for Venus, Uranus and Neptune (from my questions), I am sure the rest of the solar system planet tags have either already been made or will be soon.  We also have an exoplanet tag for any planet outside of our solar system.

What do members think of a tag for each of the major planets in our solar system, as there are tremendous scope for questions related to individual planets.

General tags such as dwarf planets, asteroids, exoplanets - as there are many of these in existence. Perhaps the only exceptions to this would be for particular cases such as Pluto, Titan etc.

What do people think of this?

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty likely that tags will be introduced for all the interesting objects in the universe as people ask about them.  [Singleton tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149385/1438) don't tend to be very useful, but if there's one question on a planet, the odds are good another one will be asked at some point.  It's perfectly ok to have a general tag ([exoplanet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exoplanet)) and a specific tag (say, [51-peg-b](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/51-peg-b)) on the same question.